Navigation issue in flutter for previous screen
in my app I have Sixth screen each screen have one button .when you click the button you navigate to next screen. I want to try when you hit screen button you navigate to third screen and remove fourth,fifth & sixth screen from the navigation stack and after in my navigation stack on three screen first,second & third
I use this code
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const thirdScreen()),(Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst
                    ); 


Use this code
Navigator.of (context).pushAndRemoveUntil(   MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => const ThirdScreen()),   (path<dynamic> path) => path.first || route.settings.name == '/second', . );


I can not use route name so it can work? @jithesh Kumar

Use this
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ThirdScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst || route.settings.name == '/first_screen', );

I can not use route name so it can work?

You can also archive this thing using this way,
void onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
  // Pop screens until you reach the first screen
  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => Navigator.of(context).first == route);

  // Navigate to the ThirdScreen
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdScreen()));
}

